# Need help identifying a fruit tree in backyard

Tags: identification, fruit-trees

The tree is more bush-like with no trunk, just branches sprouting out of the ground. It hasn't produced much fruit, only 10 or so visible green fruits that are slightly bigger than the size of a standard cherry. The leaves are all green. The fruit flesh is smooth, not fuzzy.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you add a picture taken at a distance and one that is closer to the fruit?  I can't really see very much in your picture

Comment: Absolutely! I've never used this before, so bear with me as I figure out how to add more than one photo, but I did add another - please lmk if you need more!

Comment: Can you say where in the world your backyard is? And give us an idea of how tall the plant is? A close-up of the fruit would be useful, with something to give an idea of scale.

Comment: In the PNW. The tree is at least 20' tall, and the fruit is the size of a large cherry, but still green and looking like they're getting bigger, which led me to think they are plums.

Comment: From first glance, it looks like a greengage. The photos don't help very much. It is important to see the growth habit of the whole plant, but that's just one aspect. What would help more are: 1. closeup photos of the leaves by themselves and attached to the branch so we can see their structure and shape
2. A closeup photo of flowers and their attaching branch (important for fruits)
3. A closeup of the fruit in full, and then sliced in half with their seed
4. and the seed, from different angles

Comment: Thanks. As mentioned above in my post, there are no flowers. The photos include both the fruit and the leaves, which can be zoomed in on to see detail. I can post more photos.